# Passing a Parameter in to Route PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a basic route system set up and want to pass a parameter through the url to use as the ID

button view is:

```
<p><a href="/card/?idcard=<?= $carded->getId(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View More</a></p>
```

which give me a URL of : card/?idcard=xy11-25

The controller for the card page is :

```
use Pokemon\Pokemon;

$id = Pokemon::Card()->find($_GET['idcard']);

require 'views/card.view.php';
```

and the route file looks like

```
$router->define([
    '' => 'controllers/index.php',
    'about' => 'controllers/about.php',
    "card" => 'controllers/card.php',
    'contact' => 'controllers/contact.php',
    'search' => 'controllers/search.php'
]);
```

and lastly my .htaccess file is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

hopefully that makes sense

Edit| add router class

```
class Router {
    protected $routes = [];

    public static function load($file) {
        $router = new static;
        require $file;
        return $router;
    }

    public function define($routes){
        $this->routes = $routes;
    }

    public function direct($uri){
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes)){
            return $this->routes[$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this URI.');
    }
}
```

So at the moment the router is throwing an exception, whats the best way to achieve getting the ID from the url.

Comment: Did you create your router class ?

Comment: Yes ill add it as an edit